# pbiviz start error "Failed to generate visualPlugin.ts"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

I am learning about powerbi. I am doing fine until I have to create the custom visuals. I did according to the instruction. However, when I run the command pbiviz start, I received the following error. [image: Error visualPlugin.ts]

I just started learning powerbi a week ago and I have no idea how to solve it. And I tried to apply the solutions I have found online but all of them couldn't solve my issue. I am stuck here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I now got the answer. It happened because of the v17 of nodejs. After I had uninstalled it and installed [v16 of nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), then the issue was solved.